# Ubuntu 22.04 suspends when un/plugged and spontaneously

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management

I love Ubuntu and I'm very grateful it exists. But once in a while I feel thrown back to the stone ages and want to stab my laptop in the face. I've finally upgraded to 22.04, now the laptop seems to suspend spontaneously. However, it quite reliably suspends when the charger is plugged or unplugged (USB-C).

Specifically, it will first lock the screen; after I unlock, it will suspend after a few seconds.

I see from `/var/log/syslog` that

```
... z systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
```

but can't find useful information before that, especially nothing when it happens spontaneously.

I have set:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'
```

and obviously I still want the laptop to suspend on lid-close:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
```

Please advise towards a more complete diagnosis. Thank you.

Comment: A better way to look at the logs: `sudo journalctl --since="-10 minutes"`